# How to return the largest integer in a string with numbers and letters?

Tags: python

For this question, I want to return the largest integer when it is mixed in with other integers and strings. When I test my code, I get my answer as 319, instead of 51. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Test case:

```
>>>biggestBuried('abcd51kkk3kk19ghi')
319


def biggestBuried(s):
    new_string = ''
    biggest = 0
    for num in s:
        if num >= '0' and num <= '9':
            new_string += num
        else:
            if not(num >= '0') and not(num <= '9'):
                return 0
            if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest:
                biggest = int(new_string)
                new_string = ''
                if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest:
                    biggest = int(new_string)
    return biggest
```

Comment: What's the logic? Why couldn't it be 513?

Comment: If you can use any function I suggest you use itertools.groupby

Comment: Why isn't the answer `51319`?

Comment: I want the answer  to be 51 because that's the largest integer in the string

Comment: @Barmar He means integers separated with strings

Comment: BTW, `not(num >= '0'` can be written more clearly as `num < '0'`

Comment: But you can also use the built-in `num.isnumeric()`

Comment: `if not(num >= '0') and not(num <= '9'):` will never be true. If it's less than '0' it can't also be greater than '9' (assuming ASCII character ordering). I'm not sure why you would want to return 0 in that case, anyway.

Comment: Does the string contain any negative numbers? If so, how are they represented, e.g. -3 vs (3). Also, are the numbers just integers, or do they include decimals as well?

Comment: no negative numbers, the numbers are just integers

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your loop is that you're only setting `new_string = ''` when you find a bigger number. You need to empty this whenever you get to the end of a number, even if it's not bigger.

Also, when you get to the end, you need to check if `new_string` is bigger, in case the string ends with a number. I think you were trying to do that, but the indentation was wrong -- it needs to be outside the `for` loop.

```
def biggestBuried(s):
    new_string = ''
    biggest = 0
    for num in s:
        if num.isnumeric():
            new_string += num
        else: # We're at the end of a number
            if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest: # Check if it's a bigger number
                biggest = int(new_string)
            new_string = '' # Start a new number
    if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest: # Check if the final number is biggest
        biggest = int(new_string)

    return biggest
```

Comment: How can we do it without using that?

Comment: or just `max((int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', s)))`

Comment: @Alexander I know it can be a one-liner, I just felt it would be clearer to show all the steps

Comment: How do we do it without using re.findall()?

Comment: I'm still confused. How do we empty the string when we get to the end of the number?

Comment: `new_string = ''`

Comment: The only difference is that I took that line out of the `if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest:`

Comment: yes, I see it was indented outside the if statement

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is close, but you need to reset your `new_string` after the first occurrence of a character.

```
new_string = ''
if new_string and int(new_string) > biggest:
```

This part of your code above will never run because `new_string` always evaluates to `False`.

```
def biggestBuried(s):
    max_val = 0
    number = ''
    for c in s:
        if c.isnumeric():
            number += c
            if int(number) > max_val:
                max_val = int(number)
        else:
            # Encountered non-numeric character. Reset number.
            number = ''
    return max_val
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a lot of comments to explain the code, hopefully it's not too messy!

```
def biggestBuried(s):

    str_numbers = [str(i) for i in range(0,10)] # create a list of string numbers from 0 to 9

    list_int = []  # empty list to be filled with all integers found in string
    temp = str()  # a temporay string needed to extract each integer

    for char in s:  # loop all the characters of the string
        if char in str_numbers:  # if the character is a number ...
            temp += char   # ...add the character to the temporary string
        else:   
            if temp:   # if the temporary string is not empty (i.e. integer previously found)
                list_int.append(int(temp))   # add the integer found to the list...
            temp = ''   # ... and reset the temporary string

    if temp:  # this is for including the last integer found, in the case it's located right at the end of the string
        list_int.append(int(temp))

    return max(list_int)  # maximum integer among all those found
```

Test:

```
biggestBuried('abcd51kkk3kk19ghi')
>> 51

biggestBuried('abcd51kkk3kk19ghi60')
>> 60
```

EDIT: changed the answer according to request in the comments (without try/except)

Comment: How do we do it without try and except?

Comment: @deezy, corrected and answer edited. Probably I like it better this way as well.